# How to launch screen flow on field update?

Tags: visual-workflow

I want to launch popup before/after closing the opportunity. Based on user input I want to clone opportunity and related object. The popup should open without clicking on action button. What are the possible ways to achieve this?

Comment: That is not possible in the standard UI.  You would have to build a screen flow to replace the standard record entry process.

Comment: Is it possible using screen flow?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can open a Modal currently on default close and open of an opportunity. There needs to be some point of entry.